# IVR - Tells you your cellphone credit

Tags: asterisk, gsm, telephony, ivr

I was tasked with developing an application that would be able to tell someone their cellphone credit balance via some IVR system. I dont know where to begin. Does anyone have a knowledge of GSM who could be able to give me some directions for this project.

Comment: I can help you out with this.  Where is the current balance data stored?

Comment: I work on phone company we have an IVR system for the office. And the current balance is on Ericsson Charging system(AIR). I can get to read out the balance in Java but I do not know how to integrate with the IVR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Asterisk AGI scripts](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI). They allow you to do more than Asterisk API. I currently have lots of AGI scripts in Perl but it says that Java is also supported. Maybe [this link](http://asterisk-java.org/latest/tutorial.html) will help you. Basically you will create some extended Java app which will return you current Balance. Asterisk IVR would read this value from AGI and then play it.

Comment: Thanks, Ok I would check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk may be a good solution for your problem. Asterisk provide the API Asterisk Gateway Interface(AGI), that allows you to control the call flow using an external programming language, including Java.

Some of the libraries/frameworks that implement AGI in Java are: [astivetoolkit.org](http://astivetoolkit.org) and [asterisk-java.org](http://asterisk-java.org).

Good luck.